# Error adding a new node to Windows Failover Cluster Service - Parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, windows-cluster

We are trying to add new nodes to an existing Windows Failover Cluster (WFCS).  When we run the Add Node wizard in Failover Cluster Manager, or run the Add-ClusterNode in PowerShell, we get the same cryptic error "The parameter is incorrect".  No further information is provided in the cluster logs or any of the event logs.

> The server 'servername' could not be added to the cluster.
> An error occurred while adding node 'servername' to cluster 'clustername'.
>
> The parameter is incorrect

These are Windows 2012r2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing (except add a 2016 server in) and get the same message. Haven't been able to find any logging of use that would show what the problem is. According to everything I can see it should be fine.